# ASP.NET MVC Passing model to controller with AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm trying to pass a model to my controller with an ajax call.

I've looked at the answer provided by Laviak in the following question but was not able to get it to work.

[Possible Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1857748/153797)

I'm getting an undefined error with the MODEL variable when the ajax call runs.  I've confirmed that the helper class is being called and is returning a string.  Is it because the AJAX call is inside a .js file?  Why is it undefined?

My Code:

Site.Master:

```
<script type="test/javascript">   
    var MODEL = '<%= Model.ToJson() %>';
</script>
```

Helper Class:

```
public static string ToJson(this Object obj) 
    {
        string model = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
        return model; 
    }
```

Javascript file:

```
    var GstTotal = $.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    url: BASE_APP_URL + 'WashTicket/GetTaxTotal',
    traditional: true, //This setting is required to pass arrays to the Controller
    //        data: MODEL
    data: {
        aModel: MODEL
    }
}).responseText;
```

Action method:

```
        public string GetTaxTotal(string aModel)
    {

        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the javascript file that is containing the AJAX call is included after the script that defines the `MODEL` variable in your master file:

```
<script type="test/javascript">   
    var MODEL = '<%= Model.ToJson() %>';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/myscript.js") %>"></script>
```

Also I would recommend you taking a look at the [following article](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) which illustrates how to pass complex object graphs using JSON AJAX request to a controller.