# Pass model to Controller from jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

How can I pass model to jquery ajax
my code id
'@Model' is the model on the view.i need to pass this model to controller which accept argument of type login model.

```
 $('#reject1').click( function() {
          var model=@Model;
                $.ajax({
                    cache:true,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@(Url.Action("Login", "Customer"))",
                    data:'model='+model,
                    success: function()
                    {

                     //Some logic
                    },

                    complete : function() {}
                });
                return false;
            });
```

Above code doesn't work

Comment: What is the value of your model?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518417/how-to-send-a-model-in-jquery-ajax-post-request-to-mvc-controller-method

Comment: Value? It is passed as null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For corrected post data you should serialize model

```
data: $('#FormId').serialize()
```

And form as:

```
@using ( @Html.BeginForm( "Login", "Customer", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormId" } ) )
{
    //Fields in view
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Pass)
}
```