# form submit and redirect to same page with no re render

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I have a huger web form in my MVC app.
When I click my "save" button, the form is submitted and the values saved, and at the end I redirect to the same page/form.
But it re renders the whole form, when it was already loaded and there is no need.
How can I avoid that?
I want the SAVE button to behave like: save all but continue where I was.

My controller code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult FormCol(FormCollection collection)
    {
        ...
        if (Request.Form["DocumentId"] != null)
        {
        ...
        return RedirectToAction("FormCol", new { id = DocumentId });
    }
```

View:

```
<input type="hidden" value="@document.Id" name="DocumentId" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to post your form via Ajax / jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/someController/FormCol?variable1=' + $("#input1").val() + '&variable2=' + $("#input2").val(),
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data); //This is where you would do something based upon a successful save, such as alerting the user to their new document ID or something.
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error"); //This is where you know that your save failed.
    }
});
```

And change your Controller action return Json:

```
    public JsonResult FormCol(string variable1, string variable2)
    {
        //do saving stuff here
        return Json(new  { id = DocumentId });
    }
```

Comment: Tried, but it does not fire my /Controller/Action.

Comment: In order to diagnose your problem further, could you show the HTML of the form that you are trying to submit, as well as any Javascript you are running on the page?

Comment: it was the data.success.Now there is other issue, check my updated code, when I do the request on the controller, it crashes saying it cant deserialize

Comment: Yes, I just realized that I had a copy/paste error in the Success callback on the ajax post. I removed that. So it's working for you now?

Comment: In the interest of getting this rolling, you should change your Controller action to accept all the parameters associated with the form, and modify your data in the post to pass those parameters. I will update my answer with an example of that.

Comment: That is not doable, my form is huge, when I mean huge I mean 30k lines of code.. because it creates fields based on a DB table

Comment: Here is an example of serializing the form data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518417/how-to-send-a-model-in-jquery-ajax-post-request-to-mvc-controller-method. The form data would need to be passed as a json object that matches the controller action input parameter property for property in order for it to work. That means that all your form inputs need to be named appropriately for the parameters.

Comment: And here is an example of how to get your form data into a json object to be passed as the data parameter: http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/04/turning-a-form-element-into-json-and-submiting-it-via-jquery/

Comment: Well it should work the way you wrote it. I checked the JSON obj and the DocumentId is what it cant deserialize or gives the error: Invalid JSON primitive: DocumentId.

Comment: Try specifying the json request behavior on the return from the ActionResult: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464677/why-is-jsonrequestbehavior-needed.

Comment: I have edited this answer to clean up a couple items. The return type on the controller action needs to be `JsonResult` instead of `ActionResult`. I moved the data to the querystring parameters. If you want to use the `data` field for your ajax post, you need to format the data as Json `data = { variable1: "value1", variable2: "value2" }`.