# Why is my posted data null in the Controller target of this AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have modeled (no pun intended) my AJAX call on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518417/how-to-send-a-model-in-jquery-ajax-post-request-to-mvc-controller-method) from logan filley, which seems sensible and likely to work. This is the jquery I have in the View:

```
$("#btnSaveConfig").click(function () {

    var saveConfigModel = {
        unit: $('#unitsselect').val(),
        scheduleProduceUsage: $('#ckbx_produceusage').checked,
        scheduleDeliveryPerformance: $('#ckbx_deliveryperformance').checked,
        scheduleFillRate: $('#ckbx_fillratebycustomer_location').checked,
        schedulePriceCompliance: $('#ckbx_pricecompliance').checked,
        // TODO: Finish this by storing add'l emails in an array along with the three on the page; 
        recipients: $('#email1').val(),
        generationDayOfMonth: $('#dayofmonthselect').val(),
        generationOrdinal: $('#ordinalselect').val(),
        generationDayOfWeek: $('#dayofweekselect').val(),
        generationWeekOrMonth: $('#weekormonthselect').val(),
        daterangeFromProduceUsage: $('#produsagefrom').val(),
        daterangeToProduceUsage: $('#produsageto').val(),
        daterangeFromDeliveryPerformance: $('#delperffrom').val(),
        daterangeToDeliveryPerformance: $('#delperfto').val(),
        daterangeFromFillRate: $('#fillratefrom').val(),
        daterangeToFillRate: $('#fillrateto').val(),
        daterangeFromPriceCompliance: $('#pricecompliancefrom').val(),
        daterangeToPriceCompliance: $('#pricecomplianceto').val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:'@Url.Action("PostUnitConfig", "SaveConfig")', 
        async:true,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType:"json",
        data: JSON.stringify(saveConfigModel)
    });
}); // $("#btnSaveConfig").click()
```

...and this is my Model:

```
public class SaveConfigModel
{
    public UnitConfigVals unitConfigVals { get; set; }

    public class UnitConfigVals
    {
        public string unit { get; set; }
        public bool scheduleProduceUsage { get; set; }
        public bool scheduleDeliveryPerformance { get; set; }
        public bool scheduleFillRate { get; set; }
        public bool schedulePriceCompliance { get; set; }
        public List<string> recipients { get; set; }
        public int generationDayOfMonth { get; set; }
        public string generationOrdinal { get; set; }
        public string generationDayOfWeek { get; set; }
        public string generationWeekOrMonth { get; set; }
        public int daterangeFromProduceUsage { get; set; }
        public int daterangeToProduceUsage { get; set; }
        public int daterangeFromDeliveryPerformance { get; set; }
        public int daterangeToDeliveryPerformance { get; set; }
        public int daterangeFromFillRate { get; set; }
        public int daterangeToFillRate { get; set; }
        public int daterangeFromPriceCompliance { get; set; }
        public int daterangeToPriceCompliance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

...and Controller (obviously ultra-spartan at the moment):

```
public class SaveConfigController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult PostUnitConfig(SaveConfigModel model) 
    {
        try
        {
            string s = model.unitConfigVals.unit;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

I am reaching the breakpoint in my Controller (on the "*string s = model.unitConfigVals.unit;*" line), but it throws an exception because the value of "model" is null. Why? Have I got something in my AJAX call wrong, or...?!?

### UPDATE

I changed my jquery to this (changed boolean assignments and appended a semicolon):

```
   $("#btnSaveConfig").click(function() {

      var saveConfigModel = {
        unit: $('#unitsselect').val(),
        scheduleProduceUsage: $('#ckbx_produceusage').attr('checked'),
        scheduleDeliveryPerformance: 
        . . .
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("PostUnitConfig", "SaveConfig")',
        async: true,
        //contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ data: saveConfigModel })
    });
});
```

...but the Controller is still passed a null model.

### UPDATE 2

Now I changed "*attr('checked')*" to "*is('checked')*" but no difference...

### UPDATE 3

"model" is null here in the Controller:

```
public class SaveConfigController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult PostUnitConfig(SaveConfigModel model)
```

...when the AJAX call is like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("PostUnitConfig", "SaveConfig")',
    async: true,
    dataType: "json",
    data: saveConfigModel
});
```

...and also when the AJAX call is like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("PostUnitConfig", "SaveConfig")',
    async: true,
    data: saveConfigModel
});
```

...and this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("PostUnitConfig", "SaveConfig")',
    async: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ model: saveConfigModel })
});
```

Do I need the "async: true"? I don't use that in my (working) GET AJAX calls. Similarly, do I need "cache: false"? I *do* use that in those working GET AJAX calls...

### UPDATE 4

Even when I provide just some bogus vals:

```
var saveConfigModel = {
    unit: 'Buford', //$('#unitsselect').val(),
    scheduleProduceUsage: true, //$('#ckbx_produceusage').is(':checked'),
    scheduleDeliveryPerformance: false, // $('#ckbx_deliveryperformance').is(':checked'),
    scheduleFillRate: false, //$('#ckbx_fillratebycustomer_location').is('checked'),
    schedulePriceCompliance: false, //$('#ckbx_pricecompliance').is('checked'),
    // TODO: Finish this by storing add'l emails in an array along with the three on the page; might be as easy as declaring an array like this one, and adding to it as necessary
    recipients: 'platypus@whatever.com', // $('#email1').val(),
    generationDayOfMonth: '2nd', //$('#dayofmonthselect').val(),
    generationOrdinal: 'First', //$('#ordinalselect').val(),
    generationDayOfWeek: 'Thursday', // $('#dayofweekselect').val(),
    generationWeekOrMonth: 'month', // $('#weekormonthselect').val(),
    daterangeFromProduceUsage: $('#produsagefrom').val(),
    daterangeToProduceUsage: $('#produsageto').val(),
    daterangeFromDeliveryPerformance: '1', // $('#delperffrom').val(),
    daterangeToDeliveryPerformance: '1', //$('#delperfto').val(),
    daterangeFromFillRate: '1', //$('#fillratefrom').val(),
    daterangeToFillRate: '1', //$('#fillrateto').val(),
    daterangeFromPriceCompliance: '1', //$('#pricecompliancefrom').val(),
    daterangeToPriceCompliance: '1' //$('#pricecomplianceto').val()
};
```

...it still winds up at the Controller null like forevermore before.

And then, grasping at straws, I even encased the boolean values in single quotes ('true' and 'false'), but that also (probably predictably) made no difference either.

### UPDATE 5

For future generations, this is the AJAX that works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("PostUnitConfig", "SaveConfig")',
    async: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ model: saveConfigModel })
});
```

Comment: It would need to be `data: JSON.stringify({ model: saveConfigModel })` or better, just use `data: saveConfigModel` and remove the `contentType` option. But there appear to be other issues with th way your generating the data, in particular for the `bool` properties

Comment: But the question is why you are not generating your form controls correctly in the first place, in which case it would be simply `var saveConfigModel = $('form').serialize();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Either because I don't/didn't know how, or because these aren't "form" controls (if "form" controls need to be within a "form" delimiter, as these are just all the controls on the page).

Comment: @StephenMuecke: What's wrong with how I'm getting the bool properties?

Comment: Add `console.log($('#ckbx_produceusage').checked));` and check the output :). It would need to be `$('#ckbx_produceusage').is(':checked')`

Comment: Please czech out my updates.

Comment: The parameter in your method is `model`, not `data` (read my first comment)

Comment: That's where I got the idea to use "data"; maybe I was taking it too literally...still null using "model"...

Comment: Have just noticed that your model is wrong - your posting back values associated with `UnitConfigVals` (not `SaveConfigModel`) so its `public ActionResult PostUnitConfig(SaveConfigModel.UnitConfigVals model)`. But why do you have that as a nested class?

Comment: Aha! That was it. Make it an answer and I'll flag it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the values you posting back are for your nested `UnitConfigVals` class (not `SaveConfigModel`, then you controller method should be

```
public ActionResult PostUnitConfig(SaveConfigModel.UnitConfigVals model)
```

and the ajax `data` option needs to be

```
data: JSON.stringify({ model: saveConfigModel })
```

Alternatively you could keep the current controller method and use

```
data: JSON.stringify({ model: { unitConfigVals: saveConfigModel }})
```

although it seems a little odd that you using a nested class here.

A few other issues with your initial code

1. `$('#ckbx_produceusage').checked` will return `undefined`, and it
   needs to be `$('#ckbx_produceusage').is(':checked')` which will
   return `true` or `false`
2. Since `recipients` is `List<string>`, it will need to be
   `recipients: [ 'someValue', 'anotherValue', etc ]`

However all this code to build you json data not really necessary, and if your view is generated correctly using the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods, then your ajax call can be as simple as

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:'@Url.Action("PostUnitConfig", "SaveConfig")',
    dataType: "json",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        // do something
    }
});
```