# how to pass variable to property of model in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Model as below:

```
public  class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
}
```

and I have an `ActionResult` which is like this:

```
public ActionResult Create(Class1 model)
{
    ...
}
```

now, I want to fill `Start` property from another external `javascript` file using `ajax` like this:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "/Admin/Create",
    dataType: "Json",
    type: "Post",
    data: Start:"..."
});
```

How can I access to another `View` TextBox and fill that using ajax? What should I do in data on ajax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a model in jQuery $.ajax() post request to MVC controller method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518417/how-to-send-a-model-in-jquery-ajax-post-request-to-mvc-controller-method)

Comment: `data: { Start: $(yourTextBox).val() },`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your reply but in `ActionResult` it get `model`.how can i access to model `property`?

Comment: @mojtaba1390 model.Start ..

Comment: Sorry, Not sure I understand your comment - if the value of the textbox is (say) 12/6/2016, then `model.Start` will be 12/6/2016

Comment: @StephenMuecke unfortunately it does not work

Comment: Of course it works.

Comment: javascript file did not recognize `model.Start` because i have not any model in my `javascript` file.i want just access to that property without model.

Comment: What do you mean _model.Start_? You have said you want the value of a textbox!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:-

```html
var model = { Name :"Shyju", 
              Location:"Detroit", 
              Interests : ["Code","Coffee","Stackoverflow"]
            };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    url: url,
    contentType: "application/json"
}).done(function (res) {
    $("#SomeDivToShowTheResult").html(res);
});



public class DashboardViewModel
{
  public string Name {set;get;}
  public string Location {set;get;}
  public List<string> Interests {set;get;}
}


[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult IndexPartial([FromBody] DashboardViewModel m)
{
    return PartialView("_IndexPartial",m);
}
```

Comment: What in the world does this code have to do with OP's question